# Mutation committed but state not updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have my mutation committed, but the `currentCampaign` state is not updated instead returns `undefined`. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

This is the store.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    campaigns: '',
    currentCampaign: ''
},
actions: {
    getCampaigns ( {commit} ) {
        axios
            .get('/api/campaign/history')
            .then((response) => {
                commit('GET_CAMPAIGNS', {campaigns: response.data});
            })
    }
},
mutations: {
    GET_CAMPAIGNS: (state, {campaigns}) => {
        state.campaigns = campaigns
    },
    getCurrentCampaign (state, {campaign}) {
        state.currentCampaign = campaign
    }
},
```

});

I am calling the mutation from component method like so:

```
methods: {
        markAsCurrent (campaign) {
            this.$store.commit('getCurrentCampaign', campaign.id)
        }
}
```

What I'm not doing right here?

Comment: You pass a number to the store, while the utation expects an object with the key `campaigns`

Answer (score 0):

Thats why you are destructuring a campaign var and passing a number to the mutations, not a object.

Try this

```
getCurrentCampaign (state, campaign) {
    state.currentCampaign = campaign
}
```